# ASP .Net MVC 3 - Forms, Mass edit, Strongly typed view and Validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `IQueryable<Book>` as a model for my `CheckIn` view.

I am interested to allow a user to check in multiple books at the same time. This is the reason why I am using `IQueryable` for the model.

Please correct me if I am wrong but as far as I know for this scenario, `@Html.EditorFor` will create more than one element with the same element id. Wouldn't it?

What would be the best way to create an editor form for all the books in the queryable collection and make sure that client side validations will continue to work?

Comment: `Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Id)` will display the Id value of `Model[i].Id`. If your models have duplicate Ids, so will your form.

Comment: @jrummell: Yes using that my form's elements will have duplicate Ids. But then how would client validation work?

Comment: Well, to start, you should make sure you have unique ids. Other than that, do you have a specific error?

Comment: @jrummell: I am not talking about the actual `BookID`. I am talking about the HTML element id. For example, there will be more than one `textbox` with `id="CheckInDate"` in the form. One for each book in the collection.

Comment: If your model is an IList<T>, and you create inputs with `Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Id)`, the element ids will be `_0_CheckInDate`, `_1_CheckInDate`, etc. Try it, and you'll see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please correct me if I am wrong but as far as I know for this
>   scenario, @Html.EditorFor will create more than one element with the
>   same element id. Wouldn't it?

Erm, no.

Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new Book { Id = 1, Selected = false },
            new Book { Id = 2, Selected = true },
            new Book { Id = 3, Selected = false },
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Book> model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Book>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Selected</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorForModel()
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Book.cshtml`):

```
@model Book
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id)</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)</td>
</tr>
```

Generated markup:

```
<form action="/" method="post">    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Selected</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Id doit &amp;#234;tre un nombre." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[0].Id" type="text" value="1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    <input name="[0].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Id doit &amp;#234;tre un nombre." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[1].Id" type="text" value="2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="[1].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    <input name="[1].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Id doit &amp;#234;tre un nombre." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[2].Id" type="text" value="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="[2].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    <input name="[2].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```